# Run sapply function with 2 inputs (variable and dataframe)

Tags: r, function, sapply

I am running a function to perform weighted two-sample t-tests on multiple subsets of a dataframe. A reproducible version of my code (using the mtcars dataset) is the following:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(weights)
df_list <- split(mtcars, mtcars$carb)
multiple_wt_ttest <- function(df) {ttest = wtd.t.test(x=subset(df, am == 0)$disp,y=subset(df, am == 1)$disp,
weight=subset(df, am == 0)$wt,weighty=subset(df, am == 1)$wt,samedata=FALSE)
 out <<- ttest[2]}

store <- do.call(rbind, sapply(df_list, multiple_wt_ttest))
```

Which yields a dataframe displaying the desired t-test for each subset of the mtcars based on the variable `carb`. Now, I want to repeat this, not just for comparing the variable `disp` but for multiple variables in the dataframe (in mtcars, for example, `drat`,`cyl`,`gear`,etc. The formula would therefore be something like the following:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(weights)
df_list <- split(mtcars, mtcars$carb)
var_list <- list("cyl","drat","disp")
multiple_wt_ttest <- function(df,var) {ttest = wtd.t.test(x=subset(df, am == 0)$var,y=subset(df, am == 1)$var,
weight=subset(df, am == 0)$wt,weighty=subset(df, am == 1)$wt,samedata=FALSE)
 out <<- ttest[2]}

store <- do.call(rbind, sapply(df_list,var=var_list, multiple_wt_ttest))
```

But this does not work and yields the error:
`Error in var(x) : 'x' is NULL`

I think this has to do with the fact that the original `sapply` is providing a dataframe, whereas the new `var_list` is a vector/list of variables. How, then can I combine 2 different inputs in my `sapply` function to repeat this process of t-tests on each subset of the data, for multiple variables (instead of just one) and compile the results next to each other in a table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution.

First of all, I have corrected the function so that it can cope with input data.frames with only one `am` value, such as data with only one row.
Then, call the code that runs for one variable in a `lapply` loop on the variables list.

```r
library(weights)
#> Loading required package: Hmisc
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'Hmisc'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     format.pval, units

multiple_wt_ttest <- function(df, target_var) {
  i0 <- df$am == 0
  i1 <- df$am == 1
  if(any(i0) && any(i1)) {
    ttest <- wtd.t.test(
      x = df[[target_var]][i0],
      y = df[[target_var]][i1],
      weight = df$wt[i0],
      weighty = df$wt[i1],
      samedata = FALSE
    )
    ttest[[2]]
  } else NULL
}

df_list <- split(mtcars, mtcars$carb)
var_list <- list("cyl","drat","disp")

results_list <- lapply(var_list, \(v) {
  store <- do.call(rbind, sapply(df_list, multiple_wt_ttest, target_var = v))
  store <- as.data.frame(store)
  store$variable <- v
  store[c(4, 1:3)]
})

do.call(rbind, results_list)
#>    variable   t.value       df     p.value
#> 1       cyl  2.327192 2.000000 0.145420369
#> 2       cyl  3.351162 5.000000 0.020303028
#> 4       cyl  1.068365 3.070500 0.362061152
#> 11     drat -3.335558 2.345842 0.063563101
#> 21     drat -3.633611 6.293180 0.010048620
#> 41     drat -3.455307 7.778648 0.009008048
#> 12     disp  3.069880 2.183101 0.082230383
#> 22     disp  3.897422 5.560369 0.009295961
#> 42     disp  1.697305 4.282223 0.160142699
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for this brilliant solution! This does exactly what I was looking for!